# List in a Python class shares the same object over 2 different instances?

Tags: python

I created a class:

```
class A:
    aList = []
```

now I have function that instantiate this class and add items into the aList.

note: there are 2 items

```
for item in items:
    a = A();
    a.aList.append(item);
```

I find that the first A and the second A object has the same number of items in their aList.
I would expect that the first A object will have the first item in its list and the second A object will have the second item in its aList.

Can anyone explain how this happens ?

PS:

I manage to solve this problem by moving the aList inside a constructor :

```
def __init__(self):
    self.aList = [];
```

but I am still curious about this behavior

Comment: I can see in your code above, you're assigning to 'a', the contents of A. One would assume that 'a's' contents would be identical to A's, wouldn't they?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have defined the list as a class attribute.

Class attributes are shared by all instances of your class.
When you define the list in `__init__` as `self.aList`, then the list is an attribute of your instance (self) and then everything works as you expected.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing class and object variables.

If you want objects:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.aList = []
```

in your example aList is a class variable, you can compare it with using the 'static' keyword in other languages. The class variable of course is shared over all instances.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I come from Java background where we have a 'static' keyword for static variables. Now I understand the reasoning behind this. Cheers =)

Answer (score 3):

This happened because list is a mutable object, and it is created once only when defining the class, that is why it becomes shared when you create two instances. Eg,

```
class A:
    a = 0 #immutable
    b = [0] #mutable

a = A()
a.a = 1
a.b[0] = 1

b = A()
print b.a #print 0
print b.b[0] #print 1, affected by object "a"
```

Therefore, to solve the problem, we can use constructor like what you have mentioned. When we put the list in constructor, whenever the object is instantiated, the new list will also be created.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, variables declared **inside the class definition**, instead of inside a method, are **class** or **static** variables. You may be interested in taking a look at [this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/python-static-variable/68672#68672).